# SonarQube Not Analyzing .cs Files In .NET Standard 2.0 Project

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm running SonarQube 7.9.1 on Windows 10 64-bit via the StartSonar.bat script. My backing database is SQL Server 2017, and my startup config is all default except the JDBC connection string and credentials for SQL Auth.

I started SonarQube and created a new project for my Selenium test harness solution, which contains some middleware assemblies targeting .NET Framework 4.5, a framework assembly targeting .NET Standard 2.0 that takes a dependency on the middleware, and some test assemblies targeting .NET Core 2.2 that take dependency on the Selenium framework and in some cases on a few of the .NET Framework 4.5 middleware assemblies as well.

When I run an analysis of my solution like so:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"MyCompany.Selenium"; dotnet build; dotnet sonarscanner end
```

The middleware assemblies are all scanned so I can see the lines of code, bugs, vulnerabilities, code smells, etc as I'd expect but the actual framework code isn't analyzed at all:

[image: Example of code with no metrics]

My guess is that somewhere SonarQube is deciding on my behalf that the framework project is a "test" project and doesn't need code analysis, but the info I found at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/ for Detection of Test Projects indicates that project names ending in Test/Tests and MSTest projects are the only ones automatically flagged as such, and neither apply to my framework. Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Did you try to add a new library project and does the analyzer see that project? I think you have to investigate a bit further.

Comment: I found the issue; simply having NUnit as a NuGet dependency causes the project to be flagged as a test project and ignored. However, in this case I was taking the dependency because I needed to be able to get information about the test state from the consumer of the assembly, to write to a log. Is there any way to override this behavior that you might know of?

Comment: Maybe you can try <SonarQubeTestProject>false</SonarQubeTestProject> in a propertygroup in .csproj.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `<SonarQubeTestProject>false</SonarQubeTestProject>` in a propertygroup in .csproj in my project has worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33468427)